# Day of week last year

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to calculate the date of the equivalent current day last year same week in standard SQL BigQuery.

For instance if the current date 2019-07-01 is a monday of week 27. I want to know the date of monday of week 27 last year (2018).

Current week would be `select extract(isoweek from current_date())`
but I don't know how to use this to calculate a date.

Expected output is 2018-07-02 if current date is 2019-07-01

The reason for this is that I want to compare current sales with same week and day of week as last year.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What if there is no equivalent in the previous year? Some years have different numbers of ISO weeks.

Comment: You're right. This is always a problem but this is how it is measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you going...

```
with dates as (select * from unnest(generate_date_array('2018-01-01','2019-12-31', interval 1 day)) as cal_date),
       cal as (select cal_date, cast(format_date('%Y', cal_date) as int64) as year, cast(format_date('%V', cal_date) as int64) as week_num, format_date('%A', cal_date) as weekday_name from dates)
select c1.cal_date, c1.week_num, c1.weekday_name, c2.cal_date as previous_year_same_weekday
from cal c1
inner join cal c2 
  on c1.year = c2.year+1 and c1.week_num = c2.week_num and c1.weekday_name = c2.weekday_name
```

The above query uses a week starting on a Monday, you may need to play around with the `format_date()` arguments [as seen here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported-format-elements-for-date) to modify it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks. This gave some ideas how to proceed! I will create a table and join this "calendar" table.

Comment: The example SQL returns two entries for 2019-12-30. One for Monday 2018-01-01 and one for Monday 2018-12-31 (of which the latter appears to be the correct one since it is ~12 months previous)

Answer (score 1):

This query returns no results, implying that `SHIFT` works. The function returns `NULL` if a year does not have the same number of weeks as its predecessor.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION P_YEAR(y INT64) AS (
  MOD(CAST(y + FLOOR(y / 4.0) - FLOOR(y / 100.0) + FLOOR(y / 400.0) AS INT64), 7)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION WEEKS_YEAR(y INT64) AS (
  52 + IF(P_YEAR(y) = 4 OR P_YEAR(y - 1) = 3, 1, 0)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SHIFT(d DATE) RETURNS DATE AS (
  CASE
    WHEN WEEKS_YEAR(EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM d)) != WEEKS_YEAR(EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM d) - 1)
      THEN null
    WHEN WEEKS_YEAR(EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM d)) = 52
      THEN DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
    ELSE d
  END
);

WITH dates AS (
SELECT d
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2000-12-31', '2020-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS d
)
SELECT
 d,
 EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM d) AS orig_iso_week,
 EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM SHIFT(d)) AS new_iso_week,
 SHIFT(d) AS new_d
FROM dates
WHERE EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM d) != EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM SHIFT(d))
  AND SHIFT(d) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! Even though I will use other solution this gave me good ideas for future use.